# Pandas: Ideas on how to design dataframe and append multiple csv files

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, append, glob

Hello all i'm new to pandas,

I have a very inconvenient set of csv data like this:

```
PMSN01001_PFT0_20181212_Crop_AGE.jpg_OCR.csv
PMSN01001_PFT0_20181212_Crop_GENDER.jpg_OCR.csv
PMSN01001_PFT0_20181212_Crop_HEIGHT.jpg_OCR.csv
PMSN01001_PFT0_20181212_Crop_WEIGHT.jpg_OCR.csv
...
PMSN01002_PFT0_20181212_Crop_AGE.jpg_OCR.csv
PMSN01002_PFT0_20181212_Crop_GENDER.jpg_OCR.csv
PMSN01002_PFT0_20181212_Crop_HEIGHT.jpg_OCR.csv
PMSN01002_PFT0_20181212_Crop_WEIGHT.jpg_OCR.csv
...
```

**each csv files has a simple, single string or number like the following:**

```
PMSN01001*AGE*.csv       54
PMSN01001*GENDER*.csv    male
PMSN01001*HEIGHT*.csv    171
PMSN01001*WEIGHT*.csv    65.4
PMSN01002*AGE*.csv       45
PMSN01002*GENDER*.csv    female
PMSN01002*HEIGHT*.csv    141
PMSN01002*WEIGHT*.csv    87
```

Basically, I want to make the entire dataframe look like this where filename appear as rows and values as columns accordingly:

```
                age    gender  height  weight      
PMSN*.csv        54     male    171    65.4
PMSN*.csv        52     female  181    54
```

how can I achieve this?

I think the key idea is to make an empty dataframe then use glob.glob() to read all csv files and somehow use open() to treat each filenames as **rows**. But I'm going in circles here...

```
csv_path = \mypath\  

filenames = glob.glob(csv_path + '\*.csv')
```

many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the below code where header=0 means that the first row can be assigned as the column names after reading CSV.**

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files' # use your path

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)

    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

**If You Want Merge data in row then use it**

```
csv_file_list = ["sample1.csv", "sample2.csv"]

list_of_dataframes = []
for filename in csv_file_list:
    list_of_dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

merged_df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)

print(merged_df)
```